# How to invoke a command for each result?

Tags: linux, bash, mercurial, cygwin

I want to invoke a command for each result of the executed command. Particularly, I want to invoke `hg diff <filename>` for each result, returned by `hg status`. Is it possible to do with a single `bash` command?

For instance, `hg status` returned:

```
M project/pom.xml
M project/api/pom.xml
```

And I want to execute `hg diff` for both `project/pom.xml` and `project/api/pom.xml`. How can I do that?

Comment: When you say "each result of the command", do you mean each line of output?

Comment: @Wintermute Yes, sort of. Could you look at my updated question?

Comment: Doesn't `hg diff` do it when invoked without file parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see all modified files, you could just run `hg diff` without arguments.

More generally, you could use something like

```
hg status -mn0 | xargs -0 hg diff
```

Here `hg status -mn0` prints the file names of modified files delimited by a null byte, which is a better delimiter than newline because file names can contain newlines, and pipes the whole thing through `xargs -0 hg diff`, which splits its input at the null bytes and calls `hg diff` for each token. This can be used for all sorts of commands, not just `hg diff`.